# Return true if two lists contain any common values

Tags: c#, linq

I've two lists. I want to return a Boolean result `true` if both lists contain one or more common value(s), else return `false`.

```
List<String> list1 = new List<String> { "Alex", "James", "Donald", "Bill", "Trump" };
List<String> list2 = new List<String> { "Alex", "Tom", "Jerry", "Donald", "Gates", "Trump" };
```

I know `list1.Intersect(list2)` but obviously, it won't deliver true/ false output.

Comment: `if (list1.Intersect(list2).Count() > 0){ // do something}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using Linq. As you already figured out .Intersect will yield a new list of items that are in both lists. All that is left is to check if anything is in that new list. An efficient solution can be done with .Any() which will return as soon as something is found.

`list1.intersect(list2).Any()`

See more about .Any() here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using Any() and Where() like that:

```
List<String> list1 = new List<String> { "Alex", "James", "Donald", "Bill", "Trump" };
List<String> list2 = new List<String> { "Alex", "Tom", "Jerry", "Donald", "Gates", "Trump"};

var result = list1.Any(l1 => list2.Where(l2 => l2 == l1).Count() != 0);
```

And result here is "true"